# why is my state not being set in this component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, jsx

working on my React skills, building a card match game. there's 16 cards, you flip over 2 at a time. if its  a match, they stay flipped and show the faces, if not they flip back over to reveal the backside of the cards.

this project isn't done, working thru step by step. I have added the card backs (initial state) using a dynamic reference to state in the JSX images (in render->return). they load facedown as they are supposed to. the onClick gets the id from the event properly, and i attempt to setState to show a card face when the user clicks (via 'selected' method). when i test with console.log, the proper id is logged form the event, but when i console.log the state, it says undefined.

what am i doing wrong?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Game.css';
import cardBack from '../../Images/back.png';
import j from '../../Images/j.jpg';
import q from '../../Images/q.jpg';
import k from '../../Images/k.jpg';
import a from '../../Images/a.png';



class Game extends Component {

    state = {
        card0: cardBack, 
        card1: cardBack, 
        card2: cardBack, 
        card3: cardBack, 
        card4: cardBack, 
        card5: cardBack, 
        card6: cardBack, 
        card7: cardBack, 
        card8: cardBack, 
        card9: cardBack, 
        card10: cardBack, 
        card11: cardBack, 
        card12: cardBack, 
        card13: cardBack, 
        card14: cardBack, 
        card15: cardBack, 
    }

    selected = (event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id;
        console.log(id);
        this.setState({id, q});
        console.log(this.state[id]);
    }


    render() {




        return (
            <div id="gameBox">
                <img src={this.state.card0} id="card0" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card1} id="card1" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card2} id="card2" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card3} id="card3" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card4} id="card4" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card5} id="card5" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card6} id="card6" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card7} id="card7" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card8} id="card8" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card9} id="card9" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card10} id="card10" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card11} id="card11" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card12} id="card12" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card13} id="card13" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card14} id="card14" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card15} id="card15" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Game;
```

Comment: hey, your code is working fine on my side just check one thing is `console.log(this.state)` have exactly the same value as you defined before this line `let id = event.currentTarget.id;`, cause at my side there is not any problem the data is coming and even didn't do anything.

Comment: may be `cardBack` is not coming up with any value

Comment: cardBack's value is an image of the back of the card. it works, as i load all of them in the beginning via state. you see 16 cards face down. need to get the image updated from state onclick

Comment: `this.setState( { [id] : q } );` try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState( { [id] : q } );
```

give this a try this hopefully works well.

Comment: thats it, my set state had a `,` and not a `:` syntax was bad. also wrapping it in `[]` helped

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you haven't initiated state for id

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Game.css';
import cardBack from '../../Images/back.png';
import j from '../../Images/j.jpg';
import q from '../../Images/q.jpg';
import k from '../../Images/k.jpg';
import a from '../../Images/a.png';



class Game extends Component {

    state = {
        card0: cardBack, 
        card1: cardBack, 
        card2: cardBack, 
        card3: cardBack, 
        card4: cardBack, 
        card5: cardBack, 
        card6: cardBack, 
        card7: cardBack, 
        card8: cardBack, 
        card9: cardBack, 
        card10: cardBack, 
        card11: cardBack, 
        card12: cardBack, 
        card13: cardBack, 
        card14: cardBack, 
        card15: cardBack, 
        id:null // initiating the state
    }

    selected = (event) => {
        let id = event.currentTarget.id;
        console.log(id);

        // Changed code
        this.setState({
           id
        }, () => { console.log(this.state.id)   })


    }


    render() {




        return (
            <div id="gameBox">
                <img src={this.state.card0} id="card0" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card1} id="card1" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card2} id="card2" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card3} id="card3" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card4} id="card4" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card5} id="card5" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card6} id="card6" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card7} id="card7" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card8} id="card8" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card9} id="card9" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card10} id="card10" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card11} id="card11" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card12} id="card12" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card13} id="card13" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card14} id="card14" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
                <img src={this.state.card15} id="card15" className="card" onClick={this.selected}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Game;
```

Comment: it looks like your solution is placing a function that `console.log`s the state id. i might not have been clear. i want the new image source to be the new file on click, like it starts as the image imported for cardBack, but onclick i want it to show the q image (queen)

Comment: Ok I understood your problem give me some time